# Oracle Automatic Memory Management - SGA_MAX_SIZE

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, memory

When using Automatic Memory Management, what value should SGA_MAX_SIZE be?  Should it be 0?  These are my current settings, and I'm unsure whether to leave SGA_MAX_SIZE or set it to 0.

```
memory_max_target     2147483648
memory_target         2147483648
pga_aggregate_target  0
sga_max_size          1610612736
sga_target            0
```

Oracle 11gR2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docs for [`sga_max_size`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/initparams230.htm) say:

> On 64-bit platforms and non-Windows 32-bit platforms, when either `MEMORY_TARGET` or `MEMORY_MAX_TARGET` is specified, the default value of `SGA_MAX_SIZE` is set to the larger of the two parameters.

And according to Oracle document *Automatic Memory Management (AMM) on 11g (Doc ID 443746.1)*, if you have both `sga_target` and `pga_aggregate_target` unset, then:

> If neither is set, they will be auto-tuned without any minimum or default values. We will have a policy of distributing the total memory set by MEMORY_TARGET parameter in a fixed ratio to the the SGA and PGA during initialization. The policy is to give 60% to the SGA and 40% to the PGA at startup.

So the simplest thing to do if you want Oracle to completely control the SGA is to reset it and let the default apply:

```
SQL> alter system reset sga_max_size scope=spfile;
```

(And restart.)

If you want AMM but would like minimum values for the SGA or the PGA (or both), do so by setting the corresponding `_target` parameter:

> The preceding steps [*to set up AMM*] instruct you to set `SGA_TARGET` and `PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET` to zero so that the sizes of the SGA and instance PGA are tuned up and down as required, without restrictions. You can omit the statements that set these parameter values to zero and leave either or both of the values as positive numbers. In this case, the values act as minimum values for the sizes of the SGA or instance PGA.

Whatever you do, **don't** set the PGA or SGA target or max size to greater than the memory target. This prevents instance startup.

Comment: I think `alter system reset sga_max_size;` will raise an error.  Something like `alter system reset sga_max_size scope=spfile;` and a restart of the db will be  necessary if an spfile is used.

Comment: It doesn't raise an error here (but indeed a restart is necessary), but I'm testing on 12c so maybe it's required in 11.2.

Comment: Actually no error is raised and  your statement works in 11r2 too. sorry